# Whom does this trophy belong to in Batman's collection during Crisis part two?

Tags: character, arrowverse, batwoman

In *Batwoman* S01E09 (Crisis on Infinite Earths), we go to Earth 99 Gotham City where Batman is a ruthless killer and keeps trophies of his kills. We can easily identify:

[image]
[image]

Joker, Riddler and supposedly Mr Freeze

[image]
[image]

Superman and Poison Ivy on the left. But what is after it that switch/handle like thing on the left of Clark Kent's glasses?

[image]

Comment: Can anyone zoom on the pictures?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY  you can remove "m" befoe dot in the iamge url.

Comment: I chose the best of both worlds and made the images click-to-enlarge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't thought that before myself, but this video suggests:

It's [Two-Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-Face)'s coin and seems legit to me.

Answer (score -1):

The helmet to the far left of Clark Kent's glasses could be Mr. Combustible's helmet.  It has the general shape of his lightbulb-helmet, and doesn't look like it'd be Mr. Freeze's because of the coloration.  Still a possibility, though, because the lighting in the scene is quite low.

The object to the immediate left of Clark Kent's glasses looks to be a splinter of wood to me, which would likely belong to The Ventriloquist's puppet Scarface.  Less likely is a splinter of another ventriloquist Shauna Belzer's doll Ferdie.  It alternatively looks like it could be a needle, in reference to Scarecrow's needle gloves (a la Freddy Kreugar) he dons in multiple incarnations.

Comment: What helmet are you referring to? The glass case contains ivy.

Comment: That makes more sense.  I couldn't see from the image that something was inside of it, and was thinking the case itself was the object on display.